# weird problem with putting string into TextBox.Text

Tags: c#, multithreading

I write a little socket app. Both "Server" and "Client" has separate threads for sending and receiving. Server send logg messages on Console (main thread), "Client" is 'attached' on Form that is running on another separate thread. (brief introducing..)

the thing I do not understand is that when a client receive a simple packet containing a simple string message, the client receiving thread passes it to method invoked in the form witch should just show it for user, but TextBox doesn't show the whole string, weirdly enough the same code place displays the same string on the console wright.

this method is already invoked in Form thread

```
void WriteTextInv(string s) //passed s="<0> hello"
{
  Console.WriteLine(s); //displays "<0> hello"
  textBox1.Text=s; //textBox shows only "<0>"
}
```

Am I missing some basics or what ?

and no, the textBox1 has not set "MaxLength" for 3 ..

Comment: That is not it, I can run the same code without any problem. what the string `s` really contains?

Comment: What does `Console.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);` output if you add it to the end of your method there?

Comment: are your sure you are in the primary UI thread?  .NET 2 and 4 will actually let you set the .Text property from a different thread but it will fault in the debugger.

Comment: Change the text in the GUI Thread by invoking it.

Answer (score 0):

Text box width doesnt let it show the whole string